# AngularJs: Priorities controlles calls in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am facing problem on angularJs calendar. Basically I am using Angular-UI calendar So I have created a controller called "CalendarController" in this controller I am calling service and getting data using ajax call... but I don't know why its happening, When page is loading it goes into directly calendar config line and then it goes for the service ajax call. So can anyone have some solution for this.

Goal: Need to priorities the controller calls e.g. if I have 2 controllers Ctrl1 and Ctrl2, then if I want call Ctrl2 and after then Ctrl1 will call.

```
'use strict';
/* Controllers */

angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services','myApp.directives','myApp.filters','ui.bootstrap', '$strap.directives']).
controller('navCtrl', function($scope) {
    console.log("### navController");
}).
controller('ContactController', function($scope, contactFactory) {
    console.log("### ContactController is called");
    /**
     * Getting Contact detail   
    **/
    $scope.contacts = [];
    contactFactory.getContacts().success(function(response){
        $scope.contacts = response.data;
        console.log("### Getting Contact data");
        console.log($scope.contacts);
    });

}).
controller('ActivityController', function($scope, activityFactory) {
 $scope.oneAtATime = true;
 $scope.loading = true;
 activityFactory.getNotifications().success(function(response){
  var activityData = [];
  var total = parseInt(response.data.length);
  for (var i=0; i<total; i++)
   activityData.push(response.data[i].desc);

  $scope.activities =  activityData;
  console.log("### Getting Activity data");
  console.log($scope.activities);
   $scope.loading = false;
 });
}).
controller('CalendarController', function($scope, contactFactory, calendarFactory) {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    /* event source that pulls from google.com */
    $scope.eventSource = {
        editable: true,
        className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
        currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago' // an option!
    };
    /* event source that contains custom events on the scope */
    /**
     * Getting Staff detail 
    **/
    $scope.staff = [];
    var staffDetail = {};
    contactFactory.getStaff().success(function(response){
        var staffData = response.data;
        if(staffData!=null) {
            var total = parseInt(staffData.length);
            for (var i=0; i<total; i++) {
                staffDetail = {
                    'id': staffData[i].staffId,
                    'name': staffData[i].name,
                };
                $scope.staff.push(staffDetail);
            }
        }   
        console.log("### Getting Staff data");
        console.log($scope.staff);
    });
    var calDailyEvents = {};
    $scope.events = [];
    calendarFactory.getCalendarDailyEvents().success(function(response){
        var eventData = response.data;
        console.log("### getCalendarDailyEvents");
        if(eventData!=null) {
            var total = parseInt(eventData.length);
            for (var i=0; i<total; i++) {
                var totalStaff = eventData[i].eventAssignedToForms.length;
                var staffIds = [];
                for(var j=0;j<totalStaff;j++) {
                    staffIds.push(eventData[i].eventAssignedToForms[j].contactId);  
                }
                console.log(staffIds);
                calDailyEvents = {
                    'id': eventData[i].id,
                    'title': eventData[i].eventName,
                    'start': Date(eventData[i].startDate),
                     allDay: false,
                     resource: staffIds
                };
                $scope.events.push(calDailyEvents);
            }
        }   
        console.log("### Getting DailyEvents data");
        console.log($scope.events);
    });

    /* event source that calls a function on every view switch */
    $scope.eventsF = function (start, end, callback) {
      /*Commented for testing purpose*/
      /* var s = new Date(start).getTime() / 1000;
      var e = new Date(end).getTime() / 1000;
      var m = new Date(start).getMonth();
      var events = [{title: 'Feed Me ' + m,start: s + (50000),end: s + (100000),allDay: false, className: ['customFeed']}];
      callback(events); */
    };
    /* alert on eventClick */
    $scope.alertEventOnClick = function( calEvent, jsEvent, view ){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
          $scope.alertMessage = ('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
          $scope.alertMessage += ('View: ' + view.name);
        });
    };
    $scope.onEventRender = function(event, element) {
        console.log("### onEventRender");
    };
    $scope.onDayClick = function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
          $scope.alertMessage = ('Day Clicked ' + date);
        });
        //$scope.$popover();
    };
    /* alert on Drop */
     $scope.alertOnDrop = function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
          $scope.alertMessage = ('Event Droped to make dayDelta ' + dayDelta);
        });
    };
    /* alert on Resize */
    $scope.alertOnResize = function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
          $scope.alertMessage = ('Event Resized to make dayDelta ' + minuteDelta);
        });
    };
    /* add and removes an event source of choice */
    $scope.addRemoveEventSource = function(sources,source) {
      var canAdd = 0;
      angular.forEach(sources,function(value, key){
        if(sources[key] === source){
          sources.splice(key,1);
          canAdd = 1;
        }
      });
      if(canAdd === 0){
        sources.push(source);
      }
    };
    /* add custom event*/
    $scope.addEvent = function() {
      $scope.events.push({
        title: 'Open Sesame',
        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
        className: ['openSesame']
      });
    };
    /* remove event */
    $scope.remove = function(index) {
      $scope.events.splice(index,1);
    };
    /* Change View */
    $scope.changeView = function(view) {
      $scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar('changeView',view);
    };
    /* config object */
    $scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header:{
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceDay, agendaWeek, resourceWeek',
        },
        resources: $scope.contacts,
        allDaySlot: false,
        defaultView: 'resourceDay',
        dayClick: $scope.onDayClick,
        eventClick: $scope.alertEventOnClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        eventRender: $scope.onEventRender
      }
    };
    console.log($scope.contacts);
    /* event sources array*/
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events, $scope.eventSource, $scope.eventsF];
});
```

Comment: are u using $routeprovider

Comment: no... It happens on page load

Comment: do u have sample code?

Comment: Perhaps in your HTML page, you have `ng-controller='Ctrl2'` before `Ctrl1`

Comment: yes... just editing my post

Comment: when page is loading is goes into the 2nd last of the line i.e console.log($scope.contacts) which shows as an empty array

Comment: yes.. CalendarController is the last tag in the HTML